# Distorted colors in "Ubuntu on Xorg" session, 22.04 LTS "jammy"

Tags: 22.04, graphics, xorg

"Ubuntu on Xorg" shows unreadable yellow-greenish colors, very bright and very unreadable:[image: distorted colors].

(It *is* bright, very bright, the cell phone camera adjusted the brightness/contrast, but the text on yellow is unreadable even for the phone.)

Just in case, this is what I see for just "Ubuntu".

[image: normal colors]

I managed to take a screenshot with the screenshot tool in this "Ubuntu on Xorg" mode with broken colors; the colors on the screenshot were not distorted when I viewed the screenshot from a non-Xorg (Wayland) session. That is, the software believes that it is showing normal colors.

Software: `Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, jammy`, after an upgrade from the 20.04 LTS "focal".

Hardware: Lenovo Legion 5 pro. Dual monitor configuration, the same problem on both screens. Graphics: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits) Procesor: AMD® Ryzen 7 5800h with radeon graphics.

Useful link about selecting "Ubuntu on Xorg" at the login screen: [How to enable/disable wayland on Ubuntu 22.04](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop), note that the small icon in the bottom-right corner appears only after you select the user.

(The problem that I tried to solve was that some software, e.g. SimpleScreenRecorder and the keyboard layout [switcher](https://github.com/un1t/gnome-keyboard-layout-switching) with *two groups* of input languages, do not work with Wayland; they say that there is Xorg-compatibility in Wayland, but it does not work, they say that it is possible to login into Ubuntu-on-Xorg, but that does not work either. In 20.04, SimpleScreenRecorder just worked out of the box.)

***Question: how do I fix these crazy colors in "Ubuntu on Xorg"?***

UPD

```
$ sudo -E X -version

X.Org X Server 1.21.1.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux *** 5.15.0-94-generic #104-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 15:25:40 UTC 2024 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-94-generic root=UUID=e9849d08-9d3a-425a-b6ae-a41fbde6ca6f ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
xorg-server 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.8 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
```

Comment: ``sudo -E X -version''

Comment: @petep updated.

Comment: "SimpleScreenRecorder, does not work": You can use OBS with Wayland